# Passing an object of different classes Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble putting an object into a linked list. Here is the code:

```
if(runTypes[k]==EMPTY){
      Empty creature = new Empty();
    }
else if(runTypes[k]==FISH){
            Fish creature = new Fish();
        }
else if (runTypes[k]==SHARK){
            Shark creature = new Shark(starveTime);
        }
DLinkedList.insertEnd(creature,runLengths[k]);
```

However I get an error:

```
RunLengthEncoding.java:89: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable creature
location: class RunLengthEncoding
        DLinkedList.insertEnd(creature,runLengths[k]);  
                              ^
1 error
```

Empty() is a super class to Fish and Shark.

Here is the code for the insertEnd method in the  circularly LinkedList class:

```
public void insertEnd(Empty creature, int number) {
  DListNode3 node = new DListNode3(creature);
  head.prev.next = node;
  node.next = head;
  node.prev = head.prev;
  head.prev=node;
  node.amount = number;
  size++;
}
```

And here is the code for the node:
    public class DListNode3 {

```
    public Empty creature;
    public DListNode3 prev;
    public DListNode3 next;
    public int amount;

    DListNode3(Object creature) {
        this.creature = creature;
        this.amount = 1;
        this.prev = null;
        this.next= null;
    }

    DListNode3() {
        this(null);
        this.amount = 0;
    }
    }
```

I don't know what to do and I am new to OOP. Any advice?

Comment: I think you are facing scope of variable problem [What is meant by Scope of a variable?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141133/what-is-meant-by-scope-of-a-variable)

Comment: `creature` is out of scope when you try to use it. You need to declare the variable outside of the `if`, and then assign it within the if.

Comment: As others have stated, you have an issue with the scope of your variables. Once you understand that, also be sure to check what kinds of objects you want to add to your list. It appears that you want to add `Empty`, `Shark`, and `Fish` objects. However, your `insertEnd()` method only allows you to add `Empty` objects.

Comment: I have two comments/questions: What does the `Empty` class represent? Is this supposed to be the lack of an element in your list? If so, you should consider just using `null`, which is the standard Java idiom used for this idea. Also, as far as inheritance goes, does it make sense to say that a `Shark` *is a* `Empty`? This is the typical test to help decide whether one class should extend another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you we declare a variable as follows -

```
if(runTypes[k] == EMPTY) {
      Empty creature = new Empty();
}
```

the variable is local to the block (`{}`) within which it is declared. And it's not visible outside that block.

And you are trying to use it outside -

```
DLinkedList.insertEnd(creature,runLengths[k]);
```

where it's not visible. So, the compiler is complaining.

You can do something as follows to resolve the issue -

```
Empty creature = null; //Empty can be the variable type, it's the parameter type in the insertEnd method
if(runTypes[k] == EMPTY) {
     creature = new Empty(); //no problem, it's the same class
} else if(runTypes[k] == FISH) {
     creature = new Fish(); //no problem, Fish is a subclass
} else if (runTypes[k] == SHARK) {
     creature = new Shark(starveTime); //no problem, Shark is a subclass of Empty
}
DLinkedList.insertEnd(creature, runLengths[k]);
```

Comment: This proposed solution introduces a new problem: three separate variables with the same name. I doubt this will solve the OP's implied problem of adding to the list objects which are created from different classes.

Comment: Was editing the original version, but had to leave in the middle :(. But now it's fixed.

Comment: No problem. I didn't downvote after all since you *do* address the compiler error. However, we now hit another issue: the classes `Empty`, `Fish`, and `Shark` are not given by the OP, so we do not know if `creature = new Fish()` will compile.

Comment: But the OP has stated that Empty is a super-class of Fish and Shark, right? If that's the case then that shouldn't be of any problem.

Comment: This was the solution I found.

Comment: @BheshGurung I missed that detail. ;-(